# Derivative of $3xy$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am confused im trying to get the derivative of $3xy$ out of this entire equation $$y= 4x^5 + 3xy + 5$$

Do I use the product rule here?

When I take the derivative, I try product rule.

$$(3)(y) \times (3x)(1)$$

So then I get  $$3y \times 3x$$

Am I on the right track?

Maybe I am lost but I am assuming its product rule unless its another tactic I have to use here?

Comment: @soniccool Kindly use upper case "I" instead of lower case "i" to denote self. Using lower case "i" is incorrect. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172/is-it-alright-to-use-lowercase-i-or-should-you-always-use-i-uppercase
I edited few of your post to change lower case "i" to upper case "I".

Answer (score 2):

It is $3x \frac{dy}{dx}+3 y$  if you are using implicit differentiation.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$. We have $$y = 4x^5 + 3xy + 5$$ Hence, $$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{d(4x^5 + 3xy + 5)}{dx} = \dfrac{d(4x^5)}{dx} + \dfrac{d(3xy)}{dx} + \dfrac{d(5)}{dx} = 20x^4 + \dfrac{d(3xy)}{dx}$$
Using product rule, we have that
$$\dfrac{d(3xy)}{dx} = 3 \dfrac{d(xy)}{dx} = 3 \left(x \dfrac{dy}{dx} + \dfrac{dx}{dx} \cdot y \right) = 3 \left(y + x \dfrac{dy}{dx} \right)$$
Hence, we get that
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 20x^4 +3y + 3x \dfrac{dy}{dx} \implies \dfrac{dy}{dx} \left( 1-3x\right) = 20x^3 +3y \implies \dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{20x^4 +3y}{1-3x}$$